# ansible code for multiple tomcat instances on a server

Tags: tomcat, ansible

I am writing a ansible playbook to deploy a given number (1-10) of tomcat instances on one server. I was almost able complete it but stuck at a point where I would need to define unique ports for each tomcat instance. My plan was to use jinja2 template for server.xml. I was only able to create server.xml for one instance, when trying to add numbers in a sequence to ports it fails. Here's what i had:

```
 vars:
    location: /app/tomcat
    instances: 3
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (item+8080)|int|abs }}"
    with_sequence: start=1 end={{ instances }}
```

I get this:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ (item+8080)|int|abs }}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found"}

Any suggestions on what could be a better way to construct port numbers dynamically for a give number of instances?

Answer (score 0):

The task below does the job

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item|int + 8080 }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1, instances + 1)|list }}"
```

Comment: this was very helpful Vladimir. Thank you very much.